# How to rotate camera around the player after level up in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple game in unity and I want when level up, simple when player trigger to collider, Camera start rotate around the player.

How can I do this?

I am using C# script, and I assign a camera and player to it. My code is not working yet.

This is my Code here:

```
public Camera MainCam;
public GameObject target;

if (!failLevel && !level_up)
{
    MainCam.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 10 * Time.deltaTime);
    failLevel = true;

    gameEnd = true;
}
```

Comment: You should come up with the code. Show us what you tried so far

Comment: Man please edit your question and embed code within it not in here

Comment: And what does the error say?

Comment: There is no Error

Comment: try changing `new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)` to `Vector3.up` and do not put new keyword

Comment: Where have you initialized the target?

Comment: @Mandy8055 its exactly the same - [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-up.html)

Comment: Agreed @David Florek. But the initalization of target is important.

Comment: @Mandy8055 its public, so he probably sets it up in the Unity Inspector

Comment: Thanks @David Florek.Then everything seems fine in his code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rotate it in the Update function. This code will run only once. Try something like this:

```
if (!failLevel && !level_up) {
    rotateAround = true;
    failLevel = true;
    gameEnd = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if(rotateAround) {
        MainCam.transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 10 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```